# Recursively move files from subdirectory to folders in parent directory

Tags: python, recursion, directory, list-comprehension

In the following directory,

```
/Drive/Company/images/full_res/
```

there exists over 900 .jpg files, like so:

```
Skywalker.jpg
Pineapple.jpg
Purple.jpg
White.jpg
```

One level up from 'full_res' ('images'), there exists nearly the same amount of folders as there are images in 'full_res', and for the most part are named accordingly, like so:

```
..
.
Skywalker/
Pineapple/
Purple/
White/
full_res/
```

I need to move or copy all of the files in full_res to their correspondingly named folder in 'images' while simultaneously renaming the file to 'export.jpg'. The result should be as such:

```
/Drive/Company/images/
----------------------
..
.
Skywalker/export.jpg
Pineapple/export.jpg
Purple/export.jpg
White/export.jpg
```

[This is the closest thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295056/batch-file-to-recursively-move-files-to-first-level-directory-from-deeper-subdir) I could find relevant to my query (I think?), but I'm looking for a way to do this with Python. Here's the nothing I was able to produce:

```
import os, shutil

path = os.path.expanduser('~/Drive/Company/images/')
src = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, 'full_res/'))

for filename in src:
    images = [filename.endswith('.jpg') for filename in src]
    for x in images:
        x = x.split('.')
        print x[0] #log to console so I can see it's at least doing something (it's not)
        dest = os.path.join(path, x[0])
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest) #create the folder if it doesn't exist
        shutil.copyfile(filename, os.path.join(dest, '/export.jpg'))
```

---

There's probably a lot wrong with this, but I suspect one of my biggest failings has something to do with my misunderstanding of the concept of list comprehension. In any case, I've been struggling with this for so long that I probably could have manually moved and renamed all of those image files myself by now. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: have a look at `images`.  It's going to be a list of `True`s and `False`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far from the correct answer:

```
import os, shutil

path = os.path.expanduser('~/Drive/Company/images/')
src = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, 'full_res'))

for filename in src:
    if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
        basename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        print basename #log to console so I can see it's at least doing something (it's not)
        dest = os.path.join(path, basename)
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest) #create the folder if it doesn't exist
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(path, 'full_res', filename), os.path.join(dest, 'export.jpg'))
```

Comment: Nailed it, thank you. I was using .copyfile() incompletely. Cheers :)